# i need help because of these constant nulls in C

Tags: c, printf, scanf, c-strings

this is my code and I have been getting constant nulls from it so I do need a help

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main () {       
    char jojo[100];
    
    printf("name: ");
    scanf("[^\n]*c", &jojo);
    printf("Happy Birthday to %s.\n");
    
    printf("\n");       
    return 0;       
}
```

Comment: The scanf first parameter looks more like a regex filter than a format specification, preventing the function to take account the given buffer

Comment: Did you mean `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", jojo);`?

Comment: Also, there's no variable in the second printf()

Comment: thank you very much for the help i do appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters in the call of scanf

```
scanf("[^\n]*c", &jojo);
```

you shall not use a pointer to the character array. Also you need to use the symbol `'%'` before the conversion specifiers.

Instead write

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", jojo);
```

In the call of `printf` you forgot to specify the argument that represents the array.

```
printf("Happy Birthday to %s.\n");
```

write

```
printf("Happy Birthday to %s.\n", jojo);
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char jojo[100];
    
    printf( "name: " );
    scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", jojo );

    printf( "Happy Birthday to %s.\n", jojo );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
name: programmer Vaustin
Happy Birthday to programmer Vaustin
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably want this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
  char jojo[100];

  printf("name: ");
  scanf("%s", jojo);                         // use the %s format specifier 
                                             // and remove the &
  printf("Happy Birthday to %s.\n", jojo);   // you forgot 'jojo' as second
                                             // argument to printf
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Explanations int the comments.

Comment: While they might want the `%s` rather than the `%[^\n]` (but that is questionable; names can contain internal white-space characters, so the latter captures such a name correctly, whereas the former does not), they likely also want the `%*c` to discard the terminating new-line character.